# How to use JTCalendar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, jtcalendar

I am creating the custom calendar using JTCalendar. I have created it using JTcalendar in Objective-C. Now I want to use same in Swift. I have tried using Briding-Header but still it shows JTCalendar file does not exist error.

Please suggest.

Comment: i tried by using JTCalender pod . After that i have added bridging header but it gives error.

Comment: What error? can u please paste it here

Comment: @AshokLondhe have you tried using the swift version? should be easier -> https://cocoapods.org/?q=calenda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just configured JTCalendar in Swift project using bridging.

1. [Download sample code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKcGZQUXVFaHBnTjg/view?usp=sharing)
2. Drag and drop JTCalendar folder in your project.
3. Make sure bridging path is

`$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h`

4. set up IBOutlet and Delegate, rest of you have to figure out.

Comment: i am getting error if i use JTCalenderManager class .

Comment: What error you are getting ? have you configured $(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h ( bridging file )

Comment: Now i have fixed it. But need to convert some objective c code to swift. The errors are getting because of optional. Thanks

Comment: Please consider including the sample code within the post itself. If the link was to go down, it'd make your answer useless.

Comment: @Matt can you provide sample code for JTCalender in Swift

Answer (score 8):

- In podfile write pod 'JTCalendar', '~> 2.0' and install the pod.
- Create one view which have custom class JTCalendarMenuView & give refrencing outlet as calendarMenuView
- Create another view which have custom class JTHorizontalCalendarView & give referencing outlet as calendarContentView
- Import JTCalendar and implement JTCalendar delegate

  **import JTCalendar

  class ViewController: UIViewController , JTCalendarDelegate**
- Create outlet for CalendaManager and declare some variable which we used later.

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var calendarMenuView: JTCalendarMenuView!
  @IBOutlet weak var calendarContentView: JTHorizontalCalendarView!
  @IBOutlet var calendarManager : JTCalendarManager!

  var todayDate = NSDate()
  var minDate = NSDate()
  var maxDate = NSDate()
  var dateSelected = NSDate()
  ```
- In ViewDidLoad initialize CalendarManager , give delegete and set menuview , contentview and setDate.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()

  calendarManager = JTCalendarManager.init()
  calendarManager.delegate = self

  self.createMinAndMaxDate()

  calendarManager.menuView = calendarMenuView
  calendarManager.contentView = calendarContentView
  let mydate = Date()
  calendarManager.setDate(mydate)
  }
  ```
- Create Function for minimum and maximum date which you want to display in calendar.

  ```
   func createMinAndMaxDate(){

      todayDate = NSDate()

      minDate = calendarManager.dateHelper.add(to: todayDate as Date!, months: -6) as NSDate

      maxDate = calendarManager.dateHelper.add(to: todayDate as Date!, months: 6) as NSDate

  }
  ```
- In canDisplayPageWithDate method set minimim and maximum date

  ```
  public func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, canDisplayPageWith date: Date!) -> Bool {
      return calendarManager.dateHelper.date(date, isEqualOrAfter: minDate as Date!, andEqualOrBefore: maxDate as Date!)

  }
  ```
- Use prepareDayView method

  ```
  public func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, prepareDayView dayView: UIView!){

      // Today
      let mydayview=dayView as! JTCalendarDayView
      if(calendarManager.dateHelper.date(NSDate() as Date!, isTheSameDayThan: mydayview.date))
      {
          mydayview.circleView.isHidden = false;
          mydayview.dotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
          mydayview.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
      }
      // Selected date
      else if(String(describing: dateSelected) != "" && calendarManager.dateHelper.date(dateSelected as Date!, isTheSameDayThan: mydayview.date))
      {
          mydayview.circleView.isHidden = false;
          mydayview.circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
          mydayview.dotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
          mydayview.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
      }
      // Other month
      else if(calendarManager.dateHelper.date(calendarContentView.date, isTheSameMonthThan: mydayview.date))
      {
          mydayview.circleView.isHidden = true;
          mydayview.dotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
          mydayview.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
      }
      // Another day of the current month
      else
      {
          mydayview.circleView.isHidden = true;
          mydayview.dotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
          mydayview.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
      }

  }
  ```
- Use didTouchDayView method for animating when user select and perticular date and move to next and previous month if that date is selected

  ```
  public func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, didTouchDayView dayView: UIView!) {
      let mydayview=dayView as! JTCalendarDayView
      dateSelected=mydayview.date as NSDate

      UIView.transition(with: mydayview, duration: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
         mydayview.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
          self.calendarManager.reload()
      }, completion: nil)

      if(!calendarManager.dateHelper.date(calendarContentView.date, isTheSameMonthThan: mydayview.date)){
          if(calendarContentView.date.compare(mydayview.date) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending)
          {
              calendarContentView.loadNextPageWithAnimation()
          }
          else{
              calendarContentView.loadPreviousPageWithAnimation()
          }
      }
    }
  ```